# Best way to return the sum aggregation of a relations property

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a simple structure where a post has many votes. A vote has an "value" property which is either 1 or -1

When reading all posts I'd love to select this sum for each post into a custom property on post level. Currently i do this

```
    $posts = Post::where('published_at', '<=', $date)
        ->orderBy('published_at', 'desc')
        ->simplePaginate(20);

    $posts->each(function($post) {
        $post->overallRating = $post->getRating();
    });
```

This is fully working, however I think it's not that good to make like 20 queries to the database to read the ratings. Is there a way to simplify this in the actual fetch of the posts?

```
public function getRating()
{
    return $this->votes->sum('value');
}
```

Comment: Could you show the `getRating()` method?

Comment: added it to the post

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the votes included in the in the pagination results then I would suggest adding `with('votes')` so they're at least eager loaded i.e.

```
$posts = Post::with('votes')
    ->where('published_at', '<=', $date)
    ->orderBy('published_at', 'desc')
    ->simplePaginate(20);
```

---

However, if you don't want/aren't bothered about having the votes and you just want the ratings for each post you could add the following scope to your `Post` model:

```
public function scopeWithRating(Builder $query)
{
    if (is_null($query->getQuery()->columns)) {
        $query->select([$query->getQuery()->from . '.*']);
    }

    $query->selectSub(
        $this->votes()->getRelationExistenceQuery(
            $this->votes()->getRelated()->newQuery(), $query, new Expression('sum(value)')
        )->toBase(),
        'rating'
    );
}
```

Then:

```
$posts = Post::withRating()
    ->where('published_at', '<=', $date)
    ->orderBy('published_at', 'desc')
    ->simplePaginate(20);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks a lot! That's perfect. I really don't need the votes at this point!

Comment: @FrankProvost Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$posts = Post::where('published_at', '<=', $date)
        ->orderBy('published_at', 'desc')
        ->with(['votes' => function($query) {
            $query->sum('value');
        }])->simplePaginate(20);
```

Comment: That doesnt return the sum - it simply returns the posts with all their votes